# Cannot create docs for components in backstage docker error

Tags: docker, mkdocs, backstage

I am trying to display docs stored in repository created by backstage io component on backstage-io /docs page UI, but when I am trying to access the docs I am getting the following error

```
Building a newer version of this documentation failed. Error: "Failed to generate docs from C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\backstage-enprxk into C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\techdocs-tmp-W6iVab; caused by Error: Docker container returned a non-zero exit code (1)"
```

[image]

**Files in my repository**
[image]

docs folder only having index.md
and mkdocs.yml have

```
nav:
    Home: index.md
```

Comment: I'm also getting same error, any resolution?

Comment: @Sapna I forgot add site_name in mkdocs.yml file, that's why I got this error, You can find this kind of error message by clicking SHOW BUILD LOGS option

Comment: Mine is also fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar issues working on a local POC of Backstage. The biggest problem was that I needed to install pip, python, mkdocs, and mkdocs-techdocs-core (i.e. `pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core`). If you have done that and then followed everything [in this documentation](https://backstage.io/docs/features/techdocs/creating-and-publishing), then it should start working. Hope that helps. I spent a couple of days trying to get past these types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above issue is fixed by using below as it was not working inside my container in kubernetes.

I changed app-config.yaml -

```
techdocs:
  builder: 'local' # Alternatives - 'external'
  generator:
    runIn: 'local' // changed from docker to local here
```